# image validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to validate the form in the following  code.

**Controller:**

```
public function do_register()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Details', 'required|min_length[4]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else
    {
        $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
        $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext;
        if($path!='')
        {
            $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
            $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);
            $data['img']=$im;
        }

        $this->search_model->register_user($data['img']);
        $this->load->view('register_view'); 
    }
}   
function generateRandomString()
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}   
function do_upload($img)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $config['max_size'] = '1024 ';

    $config['file_name'] = $img;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))

    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;
    }
    return;
}
```

If I leave the image field , and do registration then I got the error

> Error Number: 1048 undefined variable data  and column `'img'` cannot be null.

I think validation is not working in the case of image field? How to solve this issue?

Comment: If the image is not required always, then do not specify it as `not null` in the db ?

Comment: But i am not specify the image as not null  then how does it occur?

Comment: does your `$data` array has `img` key

Answer (score 1):

Here you were getting a database error not a PHP error so in order to validate your image field within PHP side you can check it as

```
if($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4){
   // then insert or upload will be done
}else{
   // please select an image
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. (_FYI : You can accept or upvote an answer which really helps you._)

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) 
    {
    //User did not uploaded file. Use default image 
    }
    else
    {
    //User uploaded the file. Do something
    }
```